# Is "cattle herds" grammatical?

Tags: phrases, grammaticality, nouns, grammatical-number

I know that "a herd of cattle" and "many herds of cattle" are correct, but what about "cattle herds"? For example,

> We drove by cattle herds.

Is that grammatical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Cattle herds" would be ok because it is specifying the type of herd with the word, "cattle," acting as a modifier. It's just like, "cement road," or, "glass wall."

Comment: I agree with Carter. If you know that it's a bunch of dairy cattle, you could say it's a [*dairy herd*](http://www.dairyherd.com/), or if it's a bunch of beef cattle, you could say it's a [*beef herd.*](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/beef+herd)

Comment: ...and if you see both a dairy herd and a beef herd, then you have seen cattle herds.